# How to reject mails sent to a mail adress found with a ldap lookup

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to reject emails sent to specific email addresses with an LDAP lookup.

I have made this ldap lookup table:

```
version = 3
timeout = 100

## set the size_limit to 1 since we only
## want to find one email address match
size_limit = 1
expansion_limit = 0

start_tls = no
tls_require_cert = no

server_host = ldaps://ldap.xxxx.test/
search_base = ou=NoEmail, ou=xxxx,dc=xxxx,dc=xxx,dc=test
scope = sub
query_filter = (|(|(mail=%s@xxxx.test(mail=%s@xxxx.test))(uid=%s))
result_attribute = mail
result_filter = reject

bind = yes
bind_dn = cn=ldap-user,ou=SystemUsers,dc=xxxx,dc=xxx,dc=test
bind_pw = xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

If I run the command `postmap -q USERNAME ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-deleted.cf`, I get the output: `reject`, but postfix still accepts the mail.

I have tried both with `smtpd_restriction_classes` and `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = noauth
noauth = check_recipient_access ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-deleted.cf
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-deleted.cf, permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
```

I also have tried with `smtpd_helo_restrictions`

```
smtpd_helo_restrictions = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-deleted.cf
```

The logs just show this:

```
Sep 21 09:11:45 tst postfix/qmgr[4354]: CEDFB26DA14: from=<test.1@xxxx.test>, size=769, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 21 09:11:45 tst postfix/smtpd[4383]: disconnect from unknown[xxxxxxxxxx] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=7
Sep 21 09:11:45 tst postfix/local[4388]: CEDFB26DA14: to=<USERNAME@xxxx.test>, relay=local, delay=0.19, delays=0.13/0.01/0/0.05, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
```

Comment: looks like a mismatch between a lookup for *users* and a restriction check for *full addresses*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the `local_recipient_maps`, that locks in postfix to only accept mails to users I have specified in a ldap file

```
local_recipient_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-active.cf
```